# Ctrl+Shift+Right arrow doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

I can't select words to the right by using the standard shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+Right arrow**.

By the way, words selection to the left with **Ctrl+Shift+Left arrow** works well.

Probably, the ReSharper keyboard layout creates this trouble.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this in Visual Studio 2019 in the **Tools > Options** window.

Select **Environment > Keyboard** and paste `Edit.WordNextExtend` into the "Show commands containing" field.

Then proceed as shown by the red arrows in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Had same issue with VS2019 and same possibly Resharper messing. Helped once changed the mapping scheme (top line in screenshot) from Visual Studio to Default as you have.

Comment: Riga, that would mean it will remap also the useful resharper keyboard mappings :(